# fixed menu issue, menu stacks vertically when fixed

Tags: html, css, fixed

im building a personal portfolio for school projects. and i ran in to a problem. i want to make my desktop menu fixed, but when i do it my menu stacks vertical instead for horizontal.

my test page: http://bravitus.com/www/test/test.html
i want to make my menu as it is but fixed instead of relative.

when i place it as fixed it makes the many like this:

Home
About me
Contact

but i want it to go like this:

Home > About me > Contact

```
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39fz0gsd/4/
```

Hope you have a fix ;)

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#page-1" class="home selected">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-2" class="aboutMe">ABOUT ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-3" class="services">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
}

ul li{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: include your actual tried code , not the website name. Read it to know https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Piyush there is already a jsfiddle, doesn't it?

Comment: include your code in your question, jsfiddle is an external link, if it removed, then this question become invalid, got it?

Comment: Doesn't the JSFiddle work ? :)

Comment: Please do add your code for better referencing.

Comment: well last time i posted code here i was told to put it in JSfiddle when there was more than just a couple of lines ;)

Comment: @ThomasRavnholt I believe the point here is that you put your code on jsfiddle.net website. Now if jsfiddle.net was to go down, no one will ever be able to see what the problem was with your code. The idea of putting your code on stackoverflow is so that this dependency on the third party website no longer exists. There's the pro's now if stackoverflow goes down atleast ur jsfiddle is there :p. It's chicken and egg scenario. So becuase of this they ask you to do both.

Comment: Oh yeah, i see what you mean ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the position fixed to the ul (not the li) and add width:100% as well.

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

Have a look at your fiddle I've updated it.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense ;) it works. might just be a bit blinded by the confusion ;)

THANKS ;)

Comment: no problem, but please edit your question to still include your code as it will help many others whom might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you could simply append this rule

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

to make the header fixed on top.